# ImagePicker set data to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create an imagePicker in ReactNative, but when I select the image, I get the error:

TypeError: this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState ({
avatar: data}) ',' this.setState 'is undefined)

I don't understand why my state is undefined at the moment.

```
export default class ProfileEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        async function getRoutedUser() {
            const route = useRoute();

            return route.params.user;
        }


        this.state = {
            user: this.props.navigation.state.params.user,
            avatar: ""
        };

 imagePickerCallback(data) {

        this.setState({avatar: data})

    }


...
<Button style={styleProperties.buttonEditProfImage} type="outline" 
       onPress={() => ImagePicker.showImagePicker({}, this.imagePickerCallback)}>
    <Text style={styleProperties.buttonEditProfText}>Escolha uma imagem</Text>
</Button>
...
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `imagePickerCallback` as an arrow function or you should bind this for your function in constructor. You can read more about Handling events in React [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). 
Try this:

```js
export default class ProfileEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      async function getRoutedUser() {
          const route = useRoute();

          return route.params.user;
      }


      this.state = {
          user: this.props.navigation.state.params.user,
          avatar: ""
      };

  imagePickerCallback = (data) => {
      this.setState({avatar: data})
  }


...
<Button style={styleProperties.buttonEditProfImage} type="outline" 
       onPress={() => ImagePicker.showImagePicker({}, this.imagePickerCallback)}>
    <Text style={styleProperties.buttonEditProfText}>Escolha uma imagem</Text>
</Button>
...
```

Or try this:

```js
export default class ProfileEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      async function getRoutedUser() {
          const route = useRoute();

          return route.params.user;
      }


      this.state = {
          user: this.props.navigation.state.params.user,
          avatar: ""
      }
      this.imagePickerCallback = this.imagePickerCallback.bind(this)
   }

  imagePickerCallback(data) {
      this.setState({avatar: data})
  }


...
<Button style={styleProperties.buttonEditProfImage} type="outline" 
       onPress={() => ImagePicker.showImagePicker({}, this.imagePickerCallback)}>
    <Text style={styleProperties.buttonEditProfText}>Escolha uma imagem</Text>
</Button>
...
```

Comment: @LeonardoTorres You're welcome, please upvote my answer. Thanks.